# how to print pattern where start and end element is not same

Tags: java

How to print a pattern where `i` and `j` variable are not supposed to be printed for pattern rows? I try many times I change values without results.

```
int k = 1, p = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        p += k;
        System.out.print(p + " ");
    }

    k++;
    System.out.println();
}
```

The above code is the generated output:

```
1 
3 5 
8 11 14 
18 22 26 30 
35 40 45 50 55
```

The desired output:

```
1
3 5
5 8 11
7 11 15 19
9 14 19 24 29
```

Answer (score 2):

`p` must be updated after each `i` loop, using the current value of `k`. The following output can be generated using this code:

```
int k = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    int p = k++;
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        p += k;
        System.out.print(p + " ");
    }
    
    System.out.println();
}
```

For better formatting, you can use

```
System.out.printf("%-4d", p);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it this way:

```
int numRows = 5;
for (int row = 1; row <= numRows; row++) {
  for (int col = 1, p = (row*2)-1; col <= row; col++, p+=row) {
    System.out.print(p + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

The pattern I see is as follows:

- The first Row is designated as Row #1 (not zero)
- The starting number in each row is (Row * 2) - 1
- Each Row has the same number of Columns as the current Row number
- In each Row, the numbers are incremented by the current Row number